Current Process' Handle Count constantly goes up in my ASP.NET Core application
I am monitoring number of currently open handles in my asp net application using prometheus-net library and this value constantly goes up during the application lifetime. So as I understand process is leaking open handles but having trouble to find the cause.
As I looked into prometheus library it exports the value using HandleCount on CurrentProcess object:
_process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var valueToExport = _process.HandleCount // this value is taken

The application is running on a Windows Server 2022 wrapped as a Windows service.
As I searched through the internet these open handles can be associated to file descriptors network ports or working threads (if there are some other types of handles my application could be using please let me know).
Application only uses files for logging, with Serilog library and I don't think the issue may be there.
The application also sends a lot of Http requests from where these handles may be leaking from. I send these requests to the certain service to fetch some data, But I am using only one static HttpClient instance and don't think that some socket handles are leaking there.
Here are the metrics of the app from the last time it was deployed yesterday:

As it can be seen there are some handle releases happening but total number still goes up, it also has some correlation with "Total known allocated memory" and "Process working set" metrics:

I also looked in netstat on the machine and total open TCP connections were around 200, Nothing that indicates that something is leaking there.
To finalize my question Is there some ways to debug this issue or places where I can look into to gather more information.
Update:
I found out that type of leaked handle is Event by running handle.exe from SysInternals:

